# jq - Create an array in an object and add to it all values of objects that share a same value

Tags: jq

I am trying to make the following structure

```
{
  "endpoint_url": "assignment/import",
  "body_payload": {
    "name": "assignment1",
    "description": "assignment 1 description"
  }
}
...
{
  "endpoint_url": "assignment-role/create",
  "body_payload": {
    "roleName": "role1",
    "assignmentName": "assignment1"
  }
},
{
  "endpoint_url": "assignment-role/create",
  "body_payload": {
    "roleName": "role2",
    "assignmentName": "assignment1"
  }
},
{
  "endpoint_url": "assignment-role/create",
  "body_payload": {
    "roleName": "role3",
    "assignmentName": "assignment1"
  }
}
```

to become

```
{
  "endpoint_url": "assignment/import",
  "body_payload": {
    "name": "assignment1",
    "description": "assignment 1 description",
    "roles": [ "role1", "role2", "role3" ]
  }
}
...
```

The idea is the following:

For each object that satisfies `.endpoint_url == "assignment/import"` identify the objects that have the same assignment name (e.g. `.body_payload.name == .body_payload.assignmentName`) and add the role name to the roles array (e.g. `if .body_payload.roles then .body_payload.roles += .body_payload.roleName else .body_payload += {"roles": []} end`

I am sure this programmatic approach is not correct. I better refrain from showing what I have tried (and is awfully wrong too) and would like to ask a knowledgable person what is the correct way to achieve the expected result.

#### Update (showing a valid input example)

A valid minimal input can be as follows:

```
[
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment/import",
    "body_payload": {
      "name": "assignment1",
      "description": "assignment 1 description"
    }
  },
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment-role/create",
    "body_payload": {
      "roleName": "role1",
      "assignmentName": "assignment1"
    }
  },
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment-role/create",
    "body_payload": {
      "roleName": "role2",
      "assignmentName": "assignment1"
    }
  },
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment-role/create",
    "body_payload": {
      "roleName": "role3",
      "assignmentName": "assignment1"
    }
  }
]
```

The expected output can be just:

```
{
  "endpoint_url": "assignment/import",
  "body_payload": {
    "name": "assignment1",
    "description": "assignment 1 description",
    "roles": [ "role1", "role2", "role3" ]
  }
}
```

Though I do not care too much really if the previous/old objects still are there. Whatever you find easiest to do is ok.

Comment: Please provide a completely valid input JSON without the `...`. Is it an array of objects? a stream?

Comment: Also the output is not clear, should the result be just one object and others be discarded?

Comment: Hello Inian, thank you for having a look at my problem. I tried to provide a minimal valid example input and update my question. The file has only these two "types" of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `jq` would be to do

```sh
jq '
  ( map ( select( .endpoint_url == "assignment/import" ) ) ) as $d |
  ( map ( select( .body_payload.assignmentName == $d[].body_payload.name ) ) ) as $l | 
  $d | 
  map( .body_payload += { roles : [ $l[].body_payload.roleName ] } )' json
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. It answers the question and it works. I would like to take it a step further in another question; unfortunately it is difficult for me to be precise. That is why I wanted to present a simple problem first. I would be happy to receive help and hopefully it is useful for others too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67334934/jq-merge-values-of-objects-having-the-same-key-value-and-add-them-to-an-array

Comment: If you had posted your complete problem before (like your 2nd Q) as part of this, I would have amended my answer to be generic to suit both use cases

Comment: Thank you. I felt I would not behave correctly if I would have extended my well answered question that way. It was better to give you the credit and ask another question (which I hope is better described this time).