# jq - merge values of objects having the same key/value and add them to an array in a related object

Tags: jq

The question is a bit more sophisticated and takes [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67333141/1566187) to the next level.

I would like to present an example to describe my problem. Let's say I have the following input:

```
[
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment/import",
    "body_payload": {
      "name": "assignment1",
      "description": "assignment 1 description"
    }
  },
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment-role/create",
    "body_payload": {
      "roleName": "role1",
      "assignmentName": "assignment1"
    }
  },
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment-role/create",
    "body_payload": {
      "roleName": "role2",
      "assignmentName": "assignment1"
    }
  },
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment/import",
    "body_payload": {
      "name": "assignment2",
      "description": "assignment 2 description"
    }
  },
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment-role/create",
    "body_payload": {
      "roleName": "role3",
      "assignmentName": "assignment2"
    }
  },
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment-role/create",
    "body_payload": {
      "roleName": "role4",
      "assignmentName": "assignment2"
    }
  },
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment-role/create",
    "body_payload": {
      "roleName": "role5",
      "assignmentName": "assignment2"
    }
  },
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment/import",
    "body_payload": {
      "name": "assignment3",
      "description": "assignment 3 description"
    }
  },
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment-role/create",
    "body_payload": {
      "roleName": "role6",
      "assignmentName": "assignment3"
    }
  },
]
```

An exepected output can be along the lines:

```
[
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment/import",
    "body_payload": {
      "name": "assignment1",
      "description": "assignment 1 description",
      "roles": [ "role1", "role2" ]
    }
  },
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment/import",
    "body_payload": {
      "name": "assignment2",
      "description": "assignment 2 description",
      "roles": [ "role3", "role4", "role5" ]
    }
  },
  {
    "endpoint_url": "assignment/import",
    "body_payload": {
      "name": "assignment3",
      "description": "assignment 3 description",
      "roles": [ "role6" ]
    }
  }
]
```

I hope you can see I wish to do the following. For each object having an `assignment/import` I would like to extract all roles of the corresponding `assignment-role/create` (objects having an `assignment-role/create` and whose `assignmentName` equals the `name` of the corresponding object having an `assignment/import`) and add these roles to it.
My description may be a bit clumsy but I hope the example gives the essence away.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two different object types in your array. They are distinguished by the child keys of `.body_payload`, so let's destructure all keys and check which ones are not null. We'll use `reduce/2` for this since we need to update the same parts of our tree repeatedly.

```
reduce .[] as
  { body_payload:
    { $name
    , $description
    , $roleName
    , $assignmentName
    }
  }
( null
; if $name and $description
  then .[$name] += {$name, $description}

  elif $roleName and $assignmentName
  then .[$assignmentName].roles += [$roleName]

  else error("some required parameter is null")
  end
)
```

This produces an object of the form

```json
{
  "assignment1": {
    "name": "assignment1",
    "description": "assignment 1 description",
    "roles": [
      "role1",
      "role2"
    ]
  },
  "assignment2": {
     ...
  },
  ...
}
```

which we can convert to the desired array of objects with `to_entries|map`.

```
| to_entries
| map
  ( { endpoint_url: "assignment/import"
    , body_payload: .value
    }
  )
```